# how to shift the elements in to another array

Tags: objective-c

```
        "Session_Details": [
            {
                "Start_Time": "19:00",
                "End_Time": "19:00",
                "Time": "19:00 - 19:00",
                "Session_Name": "WELCOME DINNER",
                "Session_Id": 6,
                "Opinion_Details": [
                    {
                        "Opinion_Id": 1,
                        "Opinion_Name": "opinion 1",
                        "Opinion_Url": "www.google.com",
                        "Priority": 5,
                        "Icon": "f075"
                    },
                    {
                        "Opinion_Id": 2,
                        "Opinion_Name": "opinion 2",
                        "Opinion_Url": "www.google.com",
                        "Priority": 4,
                        "Icon": "f075"
                    }
                ],
                "Tag_Details": [
                    {
                        "Tag_Id": 1,
                        "Tag_Name": "tag 1",
                        "Tag_Color": "#000000",
                        "Tag_Order": 1
                    }
                ],
            },
               {
                "Start_Time": "10:00",
                "End_Time": "10:30",
                "Time": "10:00 - 10:30",
                "Session_Name": "MORNING BREAK",
                "Session_Id": 9,
                "Opinion_Details": [
                    {
                        "Opinion_Id": 1,
                        "Opinion_Name": "opinion 1",
                        "Opinion_Url": "www.google.com",
                        "Priority": 5,
                        "Icon": "f075"
                    }
                ],
                "Tag_Details": [
                    {
                        "Tag_Id": 1,
                        "Tag_Name": "tag 1",
                        "Tag_Color": "#000000",
                        "Tag_Order": 1
                    }
                ],
            }
          ]
```

This is my array which is getting from backend, i am taking it in to NSMutableArray, but i want to customise the data in another format like except **Start_Time**, **End_Time** 
, **Time** remaining all elements shift in to another array like

"Session_Details": [
 {
                "Start_Time": "19:00",
                "End_Time": "19:00",
                "Time": "19:00 - 19:00",
                "Event_Details": [
                  {
                    "Session_Name": "WELCOME DINNER",
                    "Session_Id": 6,
                    "Opinion_Details": [
                       {
                        "Opinion_Id": 1,
                        "Opinion_Name": "opinion 1",
                        "Opinion_Url": "www.google.com",
                        "Priority": 5,
                        "Icon": "f075"
                       },
                       {
                        "Opinion_Id": 2,
                        "Opinion_Name": "opinion 2",
                        "Opinion_Url": "www.google.com",
                        "Priority": 4,
                        "Icon": "f075"
                       }
                   ],
                "Tag_Details": [
                    {
                        "Tag_Id": 1,
                        "Tag_Name": "tag 1",
                        "Tag_Color": "#000000",
                        "Tag_Order": 1
                    }
                  ],
                } 
              ]
            }
          ]

** Please share your suggessions and Thanks in advance **

Answer (score 1):

You may create a couple of model objects:

- A subclass of `NSObject`. Let's call it `Event`.
- `EventDetails` : `NSObject`

`Event` would have following properties:

- `startTime` of type NSString or NSDate
- `endTime` of type NSString or NSDate
- `time` of type NSString or NSTimeInterval
- `eventDetails` of type `EventDetails` or `NSArray<EventDetails *> *`

`EventDetails` would have `sessionName`, etc. (according to the content of "Event_Details" array of dictionaries).

Then you would create an `EventBuilder`: `NSObject` class. It would have a single method:

- `+ (Event*)buildEventFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict`. `dict` is an object from "Session_Details" array of initial JSON. Internally this method would create a new `Event` and `EventDetails` objects and fill it with proper fields in the way you want.

Later you would utilize `Event` objects instead of NSDictionary. That would make your code clean and type-safe.